# SSRS 2008 Filter missing 'not in'?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to set up a filter in SSRS 2008, and what I need is to have the user select the values to EXCLUDE from the report. So I was expecting to be able to have a filter set up as "not in" the parameters, but I don't see that. 
Am I missing something? Can you think of a workaround?

For example, If I have sales by states, and I know that there are 3-4 states that my user may want to exclude from the report. I don't want him to have to go through a list of 50 states to uncheck those 3 or 4, but only to present those 3-4 in the list to ask him if he wants to exclude them or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stacia Misner has a great blog post on the workaround for this situation...
http://blog.datainspirations.com/2011/01/20/working-with-reporting-services-filters-part-4-creating-a-not-in-filter/

Comment: iPolvo - what a great post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is creating a dataset and hardcoding those 3-4 values in that dataset.
E.g.

```
SELECT 'Arizona'
UNION 
SELECT 'California'
UNION 
SELECT 'Great Washington Area'
UNION
SELECT 'Nevada'.
```

Now set your parameter to select the data from this dataset and the user can check all the  states that he want to exclude and these values can be put in "not in" condition in the main dataset while fetching the data from the main table.